# The relation of spherical derivative and chordal metric

Tags: complex-analysis

> The spherical distance $d(p,q)$ between $p,q \in \mathbb{ C^∗}$ is the length of the shortest curve on the sphere containing $p$ and $q$. The quantity $f\#$ is the limit $$f\#(z) = \lim_{w\to z} \frac{\chi(f(z),f(w))}{|z −w|} = \lim_{w\to z} \frac{d(f(z),f(w))}{|z −w|}$$ and is sometimes called the spherical derivative.

This is from my textbook. I don't know how to show $f\#(z)=\frac{d(f(z),f(w))}{|z −w|}$.Can anyone write an analytic proof with detail please? Here
$d(p,q) = \inf\{ \int \frac{1}{1+|z|^2} \ |dz|\}$ over all curves connecting $p$ and $q$. Also, $\chi$ is the chordal metric.

Comment: Essentially, you need to show $$\lim_{w\to z} \frac{d(z,w)}{\chi(z,w)} = 1.$$

Comment: I don't know how to show that.